# Build the Substrate Kitties Chain Tutorial Cargo Error

Tags: rust, kitties, cargo, substrate-kitties-chain

I was following the tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/
and as said in the tutorial I installed kickstart using: cargo install kickstart

And after that cloned a copy of the most recent node template which asks how you would like to call your node and pallet. So I named node and Pallet as kitties.

But as I open the kitties directory in the code editor and rename it as kitties-tutorialnew it gives an error of Cargo as:

```
Execution failed (exit code 101).
C:/Users/msi/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe metadata --verbose --format-version 1 --all-features
stdout : error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorialnew\node`

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorialnew\node\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  could not parse input as TOML

Caused by:
  duplicate key: `substrate-build-script-utils` for key `build-dependencies` at line 70 column 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try again with a fresh clone. The template has been updated and now uses Substrate's polkadot-v0.9.17 branch, pulling in new updates that should fix the issues above.
Also comment out this line - { use sp_io::hashing::blake2_128 } in /pallets/kitties/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 2):

The error here is written to you in the error message:

```
  duplicate key: `substrate-build-script-utils` for key `build-dependencies` at line 70 column 1
```

You have the same import twice in your TOML file, and so you need to remove the duplicate import.

Comment: I removed the duplicate import and the previous error was solved. But now it started to give new errors just after that. It is like: Execution failed (exit code 101).                                                                                              
C:/Users/msi/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe metadata --verbose --format-version 1 --all-features
stdout : error: no matching package named `node-template-runtime` found
location searched: C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\runtime
required by package `node-kitties v4.0.0-dev (C:\Users\msi\kitties-tutorial\node)`

Comment: Right, bu you can see how your answer to this question does not actually help someone solve the error that you posted. So you should update your question or update your answer to include the full scope of things. Otherwise, developers like yourself are going to be mislead.

Answer (score 1):

Include your pallet into workspace.
Inside cargo.toml as per instruction.

Comment: I am not able to see any such instruction. If You can elaborate it would be helpful

Comment: If you open your directory for your substrate. Scroll down you will find cargo.toml ( /cargo.toml) inside include your pallet directory into the workspace